Use of GROUP_CONCAT() results in error 1064
I have a very simple table:
CREATE TABLE `invoice_physician` (
  `INVOICENR` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `PHYSICIAN` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`INVOICENR`,`PHYSICIAN`)
);


And I want to aggregate with GROUP_CONCAT():
This works fine:
select
    date_format (max(modified), '%d.%m.%Y') `Entered`,
    group_concat(PHYSICIAN separator ' / ') Doktor
from
    invoice_physician
group by
    INVOICENR;

but this results in an #1064 error @ line 3
select
    date_format (max(modified), '%d.%m.%Y') `Entered`,
    group_concat (PHYSICIAN separator ' / ') Doktor
from
    invoice_physician
group by
    INVOICENR;

I use a SQL beautifier that helpfully adds spaces after function names, but in this case, apparently the MariaDB does not like that. Is this a bug in MariaDB parser?



software
version




OS:
Windows 10


DB:
MariaDB 11.4.2




What's the difference between the 2 queries?  I don't see a difference.

a space is the difference

No idea why date_format() is working. Under the hood the ignore_space sql mode causes functions to be treated as reserved keywords and date_format isn't a keyword all on its own. There is nothing special about date_format that would make it immune to this setting/toggle. Odd stuff.

From the mariadb documentation

For builtin functions and user-defined functions, spaces are not allowed between the function name and the open parenthesis, unless the IGNORE_SPACE SQL_MODE is set


thanks I will follow up on this. And will forward this to the beautifier sofware specialist

ok I can change that in my development environment but not in production (?). So definately my beautifier/formatter should steer clear of entering spaces here.

Interestingly  this has no problems with the extra ' ' select
date_format (max(modified), '%d.%m.%Y') Entered,
group_concat(PHYSICIAN separator ' / ') Doktor
from
invoice_physician
group by
INVOICENR;

extended the question with another function which does have a space but no error triggered

Some functions spit out 1064, some do not.

what happens when you try to change it in production?
